# component for creating images.need to upload images .the images uploaded should be saved in component created

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am creating a Joomla 2.5 component for displaying images in front end. In admin side I need to used a file uploader for saving multiple images. Can anyone tell me any source for doing it?
This is the function for uploading file which I have written.

```
        function fileUpload($max, $module_dir, $file_type, $msg){
          $file = JRequest::getVar('file_upload', null, 'files', 'array'); 
         if(isset($file)){ 
            //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
            $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

            if($file['size'] > $max) $msg = JText::_('ONLY_FILES_UNDER').' '.$max;
            //Set up the source and destination of the file

            $src = $file['tmp_name'];
            $dest = $module_dir . DS . $filename;

            //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
            if ($file['type'] == $file_type || $file_type == '*') { 
               if ( JFile::upload($src, $dest) ) {

                   //Redirect to a page of your choice
                    $msg = JText::_('FILE_SAVE_AS').' '.$dest;
               } else {
                      //Redirect and throw an error message
                    $msg = JText::_('ERROR_IN_UPLOAD');
               }
            } else {
               //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
                    $msg = JText::_('FILE_TYPE_INVALID');
            }

            $msg = "<script>alert('". $msg ."');</script>";
          }
          return $msg;
           }

        $user =& JFactory::getUser();
       $username = $user->get('username');

         $acc = 0;
         $session =& JFactory::getSession(); 

        if(isset($user_names)) {
      $more = strpos($user_names, ',',0);
        if($more >0){
            $user_names = explode(',',$user_names);
            foreach($user_names as $un){
                    if($un == $username) {
                            $session->set($acc, 1); 
                    }else{
                            $session->set($acc, 0); 
                    }
            }
           }else{
            if ($user_names == $username) $session->set($acc, 1); 
     }
   else{
    if(isset($username)) $session->set($acc, 1); 
    }

   if($session->get($acc) == 1){
    ?>



  <?php
    print fileUpload($max, $module_dir, $file_type, $msg);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWF file uploader for make your component for image  or a file upload functionality. See this link for it it may help.

[Creating a file uploader in your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_file_uploader_in_your_component)

Answer (score 0):

As Tornado mentioned, you can use the SWFUpload script. However when we tried using this, it took rather a long time to integrate as the documentation isn't very good. Therefore decided to make a standalone component based on this which is easy to integrate into 3rd party components, such as yours. Should you want to use it, you can download it from here:

http://joomjunk.co.uk/products/component-home/swfupload.html

There is also a small documentation tab telling you what needs to be done and which files to be edited.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank u.i have already seen this.but i couldnt understand their documentation.so i left out and tried my own

Comment: after coping swf folder to component.wat have to be done.i am not able to understand 4 th point

Comment: @ganesh, the config.xml contain the parameter for the component. therefore these need to be copied over. If you already have a config.xml, then copy them over, if not, then just use the whole file. Then inside, change the default value for the upload path. If you don't want to use parameters, then follow the next 4 steps.

Comment: @looder thanks for ur guidance.i got the file uploading in progress bar.but after finishes it showes file upload 500 error.is there any problem in my settings?

Comment: check that the file you are trying to upload coincides with the parameters